# Apache RewriteRule not working without Page # specified

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule set up in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^Crocodile-Style/([0-9]+)/?$ products/display.php?folder=crocodile-style&page=$1 [L,NC]
```

http://test.bradp.com/drupal/Crocodile-Style/1 **works OK.**

http://test.bradp.com/drupal/Crocodile-Style/ **DOES NOT WORK.**

Apache throws a 404. The PHP logic defaults to page 1 without a page specified, so I know the script is fine.

What can I do?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to implement this with two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^Crocodile-Style/?$ products/display.php?folder=crocodile-style [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Crocodile-Style/([0-9]+)/?$ products/display.php?folder=crocodile-style&page=$1 [L,NC]
```